# Python classes: What is the true difference between `call` and `__call__`?

Tags: python-3.x, class, oop

Is there a difference if I write a Python class with `call()` rather than `__call__()` ?

I have found both implementations, and both seem to work. Can anybody explain their difference?

People say `__call__` lets you use the instance like this: `instance(X)`, instead of `call()` that you would need as: `instance.call(X)`. However, this doesn't seem to be the case: look at this [TensorFlow tutorial on how to implement a Transformer Neural Network](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/text/transformer#create_the_transformer). All the classes created have `call()` instead of `__call__()`, yet they work very well with `instance(X)` commands.

Comment: Using the magic name `__call__` means that you can invoke the method without explicitly naming it: you just write `instance()`.  With any other name, you have to write something like `instance.call()`.

Comment: Hi, please take a look at the tutorial I linked rn. It contains lots of classes that contain `call()` instead of `__call__()`, but it doesn't work as you explained, actually the opposite. If you can shed light on this issue it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Tensorflow, but it would appear that the base class implements `__call__()`; that implementation invokes the `call()` method that each subclass defines, probably multiple times with varying parameters.